# Cannot stop timer in Android? How to solve it?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I am writing a class to control start and stop timer in Android. The controller is an Activity that will send start or stop value. In the TimerControl class, I write two functions that use to start and stop the timer. I can start the timer, but I cannot stop it. How can I solve it? This is my code

```
//In Controller class
//===========Start========
 Intent smsTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimmerControl.class);
 smsTimer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 smsTimer.putExtra("input_timer", "start");
 getApplicationContext().startActivity(smsTimer);
 //===========Stop========
 Intent smsTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimmerControl.class);
 smsTimer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 smsTimer.putExtra("input_timer", "stop");
 getApplicationContext().startActivity(smsTimer);
```

This is my code of TimerControl

```
public class TimmerControl extends Activity {
    private CountDownTimer timer_SMS;
    private String TAG="TimmerControl";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null &&intent.getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (!bundle.getString("input_timer").equals(null)) {
                String  input_timer = bundle.getString("input_timer");                
                if(input_timer.equals("start")) {// start
                        startSMSTimer();
                }
                else if(input_timer.equals("stop")) {// stop
                    stopSMSTimer();
                }
                else{}
            }
        }
        finish();
    }
    public void startSMSTimer(){
        if (timer_SMS != null) {
            timer_SMS.cancel();
            timer_SMS = null;
        }
        timer_SMS = new CountDownTimer(100000, 20000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {               
                    long timOver = 100000 - millisUntilFinished;
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(timOver));      
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() { }
        };
        timer_SMS.start();
    }
    public void stopSMSTimer(){
        if (timer_SMS != null) {
            timer_SMS.cancel();
            timer_SMS = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TimmerControl extends Service {

    CountDownTimer timer_SMS;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("start");
        intentFilter.addAction("stop");

        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //extract our message from intent

                if (intent.getAction().equals("start")) {
                    startSMSTimer();
                }
                if (intent.getAction().equals("stop")) {
                    stopSMSTimer();
                }

            }
        };

        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void startSMSTimer() {
        if (timer_SMS != null) {
            timer_SMS.cancel();
            timer_SMS = null;
        }
        timer_SMS = new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long timOver = 100000 - millisUntilFinished;

                Log.e("Time: ", ""+timOver);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e("finished: ","");
            }
        };
        timer_SMS.start();
    }

    public void stopSMSTimer() {
        if (timer_SMS != null) {
            timer_SMS.cancel();
            timer_SMS = null;
            Log.e("Stop: ","");
        }
        stopSelf();
    }

}        


    SMSControllerActivity.java


    public class SMSControllerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smscontroller);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_start).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!isServiceRunning(TimmerControl.class))
                    startService(new Intent(SMSControllerActivity.this, TimmerControl.class));
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent("start"));
                    }
                }, 500);

            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.btn_stop).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("stop"));
            }
        });
        ;
    }

    private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    }


    activity_smscontroller.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Stop" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Thanks. But in the TimerControl class. I do not use GUI. I set it as `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"></activity>` and used `Activity`, instead of `AppCompatActivity`. However, the main problem is how we can cancel the timer. Do you print the log in starttimer function? Your stop timer is similar my code. In my code, it pass the function stop timer but it cannot stop

Comment: I think i know the reason. It is when I call `Intent smsTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimmerControl.class);` then the class is reinitialize, thus the variable timer_SMS=null, Hence, the stopTImer function never do cancel

Comment: And process i SMSControllerActivity is mainActivity and TimmerControl is no GUI. When we press button in the SMSControllerActivity, it will control action stop/start in TimmerControl

Comment: you cant keep SMSControllerActivity as main activity otherwise its not possible i tried it. And also if your use activity or AppcompactActivity its doesn't make any issue.

Comment: Hence, I am looking for a good solution. The task is that I have a TimeControl class that has to stop and starts timer. I want to control stop/start timer from an activity. I think it is possible

Comment: its only possible if TimmerControl is service instead of Activity

Comment: ok.. that is my goal. could you make it using service? Really thank

Comment: Good job. I will test it on Monday and let's you know the result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send "stop" while sending intent for stop as follows :

```
//In Controller class
//===========Start========
 Intent smsTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimmerControl.class);
 smsTimer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 smsTimer.putExtra("input_timer", "start"); // start
 getApplicationContext().startActivity(smsTimer);
 //===========Stop========
 Intent smsTimer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimmerControl.class);
 smsTimer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 smsTimer.putExtra("input_timer", "stop"); // stop 
 getApplicationContext().startActivity(smsTimer);
```

Comment: Sorry. Just mistake when I copy. I used stop and the function already go to `stopSMSTimer` but it cannot stop